# Prediction in a row-by-row fashion (regression, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, regression

I have trained two different regressors based on the values of `distance` column. Since I have two models in place, I want to generate predictions, which I would then compare with `y_test`, as is usual procedure in ML (in my case, I use `mae` score).

Here is the code I tried:

```
predictions = []

for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
    row = X_test.iloc[i, 0:11]
    #row.to_frame()
    row = pd.DataFrame(data=row.values, columns=X_test.columns).reset_index()

    dist = row.loc['distance']
    if dist <= SMALL_DISTANCE:
        predictions.append(xgb_small_best.predict(row))  #np.array(row).reshape((1,-1))))
    else:
        predictions.append(xgb_large_best.predict(row))  #np.array(row).reshape((1,-1))))
```

The above produced this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (11, 1), indices imply (11, 11)
```

In the commented part you will see what I also tried, but without success, because there seems to be a mismatch with column names (models are trained with columns such as `['distance', 'weight']`, and Series object comes with columsn `[f1, f2]`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in a simple way? If this model proves to work well, I would need the same procedure in inference time.

Comment: The series could have different column names because you are using X_test_enc.columns when creating your dataframe row. Why not just loop through each row of X_test and supply that to predictions?

Comment: @P.Shroff No, it's not the problem, I've edited the post. And I also tried to go in a row-by-row fashion, and it doesn't work. Could you post the solution you think would work?

Answer (score 0):

This worked, but please feel free to post an alternative, if you believe it is more efficient:

```
predictions = []

for index, row in X_test.iterrows():
    
    dist = row['distance']
    row = pd.DataFrame(data=row.values)
    row = row.transpose()
    row.columns = X_test_enc.columns
    if dist <= SMALL_DISTANCE:
        prediction = xgb_small_best.predict(row) 
    else:
        prediction = xgb_large_best.predict(row)
    
    predictions.append(prediction)
```